# Whether to include time as a covariate in repeated measures analysis

Tags: repeated-measures, sas

Suppose we want to model the temperature ($1$ = hot, $0$ = cold) of 5 regions over the following time periods: 1 month, 6, months, and 4 years. Suppose a predictor variable is $X$ (amount of deforestation, 1 = a lot, 0 = very little). In modeling the main effect (deforestation), should we include time as a predictor?

Answer (score 2):

Was the measurement time at month 1, month 6 and year 4? If so, 3 measurements of 4 years apart might only have very weak correlations. Using continuous time as a predictor you assume 1 month to 4 years later have a well-behaved time trajectory, which is a bit doubtful for such a long duration.  Instead, you could consider them as 3 levels of time, focusing on heterogeneity in temerature in 1 month, in 6 months and in 4 years. Multilevel model or mixed-effect model can be used for this.

Comment: What is the measurements were much closer together?